# Describing vectors help

Tags: physics

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw37w.png

I don't understand.

Seems that the answers would be that everything is equal? There's nothing that indicates parallel, perpendicular, or 0, is there?

Comment: Wrong image !...

Comment: This is true whenever $\vec{a}, \vec{b}$ are collinear.

Comment: Have you understood that $\vec{a}$ is a vector and $a$ its norm ?

Comment: Do you meant that a w/ arrow is vector and a is scalar? Yes, what does that have to do with the problem?

Comment: "What does that have to do with the problem?" Strange question : why do you think that they have given you $\vec{a}+\vec{b}=\vec{c}$ (1) AND $a+b=c$ (2). (2) is an essential information. If (2) had been a consequence of (1) they would not have added it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: The (2) portion is not included in the actual problem. I don't understand its relevance. Is it just a red herring?

Comment: I don't dream... in the **first line** of the "actual problem" in http://i.imgur.com/ee0Z9mW.png, it is explicitly written $a+b=c$... or we have not the same version... No red fish on my side; I only tried to help. If you analyze things in question (a), you should conclude that $\vec{a}=k\vec{b}$ with $k\geq0.$